How to execute machine code programatically in golang?
I converted this example in c++ into golang code below. However it results in a segfault but works in c++. Any idea on how to fix?
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    // Machine code for "mov eax, 0; ret"
    code := []byte{0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3}

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage: %s <integer>\n", os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Convert the user's value to an integer
    num, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Invalid integer: %s\n", os.Args[1])
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Copy the integer value into the machine code
    copy(code[1:], (*(*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&num)))[:])

    // Allocate readable/writable memory
    pageSize := syscall.Getpagesize()
    mem, err := syscall.Mmap(
        -1,
        0,
        pageSize,
        syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE,
        syscall.MAP_ANON|syscall.MAP_PRIVATE,
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Copy the machine code into the allocated memory
    copy(mem, code)

    // Change memory protection to readable and executable
    if err := syscall.Mprotect(mem, syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_EXEC); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Convert the memory to a function pointer
    funcPtr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&mem[0]))
    funcCall := *(*func() int)(unsafe.Pointer(&funcPtr))

    // Call the function and print the result
    result := funcCall()
    fmt.Printf("Your number was: %d\n", result)

    // Unmap the memory
    if err := syscall.Munmap(mem); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}


Here is the error
unexpected fault address 0x0
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0x47ed57]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x4979a7?, 0x5?})
    /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:1077 +0x5c fp=0xc000068650 sp=0xc000068620 pc=0x430d9c
runtime.sigpanic()
    /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:875 +0x285 fp=0xc0000686b0 sp=0xc000068650 pc=0x445505
main.main()
    /home/user100/go-jit/cmd/main.go:56 +0x217 fp=0xc000068740 sp=0xc0000686b0 pc=0x47ed57
runtime.main()
    /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:267 +0x2bb fp=0xc0000687e0 sp=0xc000068740 pc=0x43377b
runtime.goexit()
    /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650 +0x1 fp=0xc0000687e8 sp=0xc0000687e0 pc=0x45cf61


Don't you need to account for whatever stack conventions Go uses to achieve a successful return?

I am not sure how to do that?

Your cast
    // Convert the memory to a function pointer
    funcPtr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&mem[0]))
    funcCall := *(*func() int)(unsafe.Pointer(&funcPtr))

is invalid. Also, you can't call this pointer, since the runtime needs to know the structure of the stack frames.
You could use cgo for that purpose: “Calling C function pointers is currently not supported, however you can declare Go variables which hold C function pointers and pass them back and forth between Go and C.”
Here is the example given in the documentation, you could adapt it to fit your purpose:
package main

// typedef int (*intFunc) ();
//
// int
// bridge_int_func(intFunc f)
// {
//      return f();
// }
//
// int fortytwo()
// {
//      return 42;
// }
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    f := C.intFunc(C.fortytwo)
    fmt.Println(int(C.bridge_int_func(f)))
    // Output: 42
}

